# Set path of a visual studio installer programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-project

I am new in creating MSI, still learning.
Here's my problem:

I have a small test solution with 2 projects: A simple WPF application, and a class library. The WPF uses the class library to get a random text to display.
Made a setup project in visual studio 2013 and successfully created a MSI that will install the application.

I have learned that i can add an "Installer class" .cs file to one of my projects to be able to subscribe to certain events like "BeforeInstall" and "AfterInstall". I can use this to write some values in the registry, like the installation path that the user selected.

All good, but now this happens: I decide to update the class library to return a different text, and i need to create a patch for my application that will ONLY update the class library (the dll), not the wpf app itself.

In order to achieve this, i have created another setup project, added the class library output to it. Presumably i have the installation path from the previous installation in the registry, my problem is the following:

How can i tell the patch setup to install to the path that i have in registry, or do NOT install at all if the registry is not present?
I tried to create an installer class .cs in the class library project, where i can write some code to get the path from the register, but i can't find where to set it.

I have read quite a few stackoverflow posts, that's how i got this far, but now i am really stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: I have found out that i can add a launch condition to search target machine for a registry, but i can't get it to work.

Comment: Also found this link, tried to do like they say, but they are not specific, and i can't really understand. Also, the post is from 2007: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/09/20/472125.aspx

Comment: After further research, i found this link that is EXACTLY what i need, but it doesn't seem to work. It says "Could not access network location \MyApp". I followed the instructions from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827026

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of this. In the Registry view in the setup project create the item where you want to store the user entered install directory and give it the value [TARGETDIR] which is case-sensitive.

You cannot create patches with VS setup projects, and neither can you make an actual patch with any tool where the only change is to custom action code. You do an upgrade as described here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/

which is old but still correct. The only thing new is that you need to increment the file versions of files you want to update in your RemovePreviousVersions upgrade.

Without knowing what "return different text" means exactly I can't help further.